# Background Image in Android

Tags: android

I´m trying to put a background image in my layout, I put the path of the file (on drawables) in the "background" propierty, it shows in the xml preview, but when I run the app on my phone it doesn´t.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"     tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/background_image">

</LinearLayout>
```

My onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Also, I was trying this tutorial --> [link](http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.fr/2010/06/how-to-tile-background-image-in-android.html) but it doesn´t works, I can call the xml file and it shows an error.

Comment: *it shows an error.* which one?

Comment: Just when I try with the xml file, when I put the image´s path in the backgrund propierty of my layout, it shows on the preview, but it doesnt in my real phone: http://i.imgur.com/kZeMvNo.png

Comment: What does logcat say?

Comment: 04-20 21:41:27.450  12942-12942/com.mookup.singup W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (4224x3168, max=4096x4096)   I didn´t see the logcat, it says this, I´m going to change the image and I will try again.

Comment: Always check the logs before posting a question  :-)

Comment: Thanks !, Too big image, I never used the logcat. Excuse me for dond read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's one case where images wont be shown, if the dimensions of your drawable exceeds 2048 pixels in any axis (on non-HD devices only).